# How does the DFS 'cache duration' setting work?

Tags: cache, dfs

We have a large and complex multi-site DFS structure. I'm using DFS for an application that would be disrupted if any part of the structure was redirected out of site (although I'd rather it be disrupted than fail entirely).

The path is something like:

\DOMAIN\DFSROOT$\IT\FOO\BAR\MYAPP

I see that I can set the 'cache duration' on any part of the tree. If I set the 'cache duration' on the 'MYAPP' folder to say 12 hours, will the client cache the full path for 12 hours or just the 'MYAPP' bit? ie. will it re-resolve \DOMAIN\DFSROOT$\IT\FOO\BAR every 5 mins unless I change that too?

Added clarification:
If IT has a cache of 5 mins and MYAPP has a cache of 12 hours, will the client start to re-resolve \DOMAIN\DFSROOT$\IT after 6 mins or will it just not bother on the basis that 'MYAPP' is cached for 12 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should cache the entire path as that is what the referral is defined as. You can verify that by running the dfsutil on a DFS client from the support tools like this:

dfsutil /PktInfo